# Parent Navigation Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to highlight my parent navigation for the button 'stories' when I am in the child menu (http://serenityhouse3.ayomo.com/stories). Thanking you in advance. :-)

The current CSS for the parent looks like this:

```
}
.nav ul {
padding-left: 20px;
background-color: #2c75c0;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 0px;

}
.nav li {
display: inline;
padding: 20px;

}
.nav a:link,
.nav a:visited {
font-size: 18px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;

}
.nav li.current-menu-item a:link,
.nav li.current-menu-item a:visited {
color: #bae2b7;

}
.nav li.current-menu-parent a:link,
.nav li.current-menu-parent a:visited {
color: #bae2b7;

}
.nav a:hover {
color: #bae2b7;

}
.nav li:last-child
.nav li:last-child a:link,
.nav li:last-child a:visited {
color: #f90;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All resolved adding the following CSS:

```
 }
 .nav li.current-page-ancestor a {
 color: #bae2b7;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css:

```
.current-page-ancestor
.nav li.current-menu-item a:link,
.nav li.current-menu-item a:visited {
color: #bae2b7;
}
```